# Can using "@inherits" solve my editor templates IEnumerable headaches?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, templates, viewmodel, editorfor, inheritance

I think it might be easier to explain by showing some code and explaining as I go along:

**Create Product ViewModel:**

```
[UIHint("Prices")]
public IList<CreatePricesViewModel> Prices { get; set; }
```

With this, I want the ability to use an ajax call to add another set of prices for a different currency to the product.

**Create Prices ViewModel:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayName("Wholesale Price: ")]
public decimal Wholesale { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Required]
[DisplayName("Retail Price: ")]
public decimal Retail { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayName("Discounted Price: ")]
public decimal Discount { get; set; }
```

In my controller I create a single CreatePricesViewModel and add it to the CreateProductViewModels list of CreatePricesViewModel's so there is at least one available instance to render in the view.

**Create Product View:**

```
@model CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.ViewModels.ProductViewModels.CreateProductViewModel 
......
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prices)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prices)
</div>
```

**Prices EditorFor Templates:**

This is where I'm struggling really. When I strongly-type to the CreatePricesViewModel I get a complaint because I'm passing in an IEnumerable of type CreatePricesViewModel instead of a single instance - but when I use a foreach loop my id and names are messed up so the model-binding fails? Can using @inherits here help?

```
@model CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.ViewModels.PriceViewModels.CreatePricesViewModel

<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Wholesale)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Wholesale)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wholesale)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Retail)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Retail)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Retail)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discount)
</div>   
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discount)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discount)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `@inherits` cannot solve your headaches.

When using `UIHint`, the entire enumerable is passed, so you need to make your template strongly typed to the list:

```
@model IEnumerable<CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.ViewModels.PriceViewModels.CreatePricesViewModel>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_SomePrice", item)
}
```

and then define `_SomePrice.cshtml` partial:

```
@model CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.ViewModels.PriceViewModels.CreatePricesViewModel

<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Wholesale)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Wholesale)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wholesale)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Retail)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Retail)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Retail)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discount)
</div>   
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discount)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discount)
</div>
```

This is not necessary when you don't use the UIHint attribute => the editor template is automatically invoked for each element of the Prices collection. It sucks but it's how it is.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was wondering about your UIHint attribute comment. If I remove the attribute and just call the editor template from the product create view @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prices, "EditorTemplate/Prices) - will this sort the problem out? Or does it still pass the IEnumerable to the template?

Comment: Yes, it will sort the problem. But your template needs to be named `CreatePricesViewModel.cshtml` because that's the convention.